# iOS9 AppleLanguages different from older iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios9

How I get now the actual system language? It seems that they put regional suffix after last dash. So before `cs` is now `cs-DE` if the language is Czech and regional setting is German. But there are some languages which don't have the suffix like GB language is `en-GB` but regional setting is German.

```
NSUserDefaults* defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray* language = [defs objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString* preferredLang = [language objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"localeIdentifier: %@", preferredLang);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `componentsFromLocaleIdentifier` method from `NSLocale` class

[Here is the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLocale/componentsFromLocaleIdentifier:)

You can do like this:

```
NSString* localeID = [NSLocale currentLocale].localeIdentifier;
NSDictionary* components = [NSLocale componentsFromLocaleIdentifier:localeID];
NSString* languageID = components[NSLocaleLanguageCode];
```

**EDIT**

Getting the language this way will create some issues if the language the app is currently translated in is not the device's language. Indeed, 
`components[NSLocaleLanguageCode]` will return the device's language.

To get the app's current language, you should use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations].firstObject`.

To get the device's region, you can still use `components[NSLocaleCountryCode]`

Comment: localeID should be NSString I gues

Answer (score 5):

I just run into this problem recently. According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH15-SW2), you will get the locale id with region designator which for like `[language designator]-[region designator]` on iOS 9.
I found a solution if you just wanna get the locale id, you could use
`[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations]`.

Answer (score 1):

One more solution, If any of you like,

```
  NSArray *languages = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
  NSString *currentLanguage = [languages objectAtIndex:0];


    if ([[currentLanguage componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] count] == 2)
            currentLanguage = [[currentLanguage componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] objectAtIndex:0];

   // Only for chinese Language.
    else  if ([[currentLanguage componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] count] == 3)
        currentLanguage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",  [[currentLanguage componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] objectAtIndex:0],
                           [[currentLanguage componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] objectAtIndex:1]
                           ];
```

"currentLanguage" Will give you your current langauge so you can use it for localise or any further use.